# Qt QListWidget addItem memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I have a QComboBox_1 with items added (both icon and text). Then i added item to the QListWidget_1 as below from a QPushButton_1 clicked(). The QListWidget forcing to add a QListWidgetItem as a pointer value.

```
void MainWindow::on_QPushButton_1_clicked(){
int intSelected = ui->QComboBox_1->currentIndex();
QListWidgetItem *Itm = new QListWidgetItem(ui->QComboBox_1->itemIcon(intSelected), ui->QComboBox_1->itemText(intSelected));
ui->QListWidget_1->addItem(Itm);}
```

And it is working fine. But i didn't delete the pointer variable "*Itm" in any of the code (MainWindow unload or close). This will create memory leak?

I am a beginner to Qt and C++

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not. Technically it's not entirely obvious from the manual, though one definitely can suppose that.

Additionally, in the source of `QListWidget.cpp` you can see that items are stored inside internal `QListModel` class which handles deletion of them automatically in its destructor and in other cases when they are removed.

Comment: Is this a general process that any pointer passed to a qwidget (or) any qwidget passed to another qwidget will be taken care like this?

Comment: @Jeet Actually no, in general case your algorithm should be -- if something you're passing is `QObject` (for example any `QWidget` is subclass of `QObject` also) in most of the places in manual it should state if ownership of your object is taken (at least for functions `add` or `insert` something). However in this case `QListWidgetItem` is not a `QObject` so you can only suppose that ownership will be taken because it is passed by pointer and also probably see some examples of its usage etc. I don't think that it's really good design but well we have to bear with it.